# Silex DBAL executeQuery() is sometimes taking 5 seconds for simple SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, silex, dbal

I found that *sometimes* this executeQuery() statement takes 5 seconds. I output the microtime() before and after this statement and measured time that way.

```
$result = $db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE slug = ?", 
    array($params['category']));
```

And the SQL query itself isn't slow, since I tested it directly in MySQL Workbench, and it was super quick (the table only has 4 records!)

Any ideas why this statement might be slow, and only SOMETIMES?

Comment: Are there multiple concurrent connections to the MySQL server ?

Comment: I would recommend that you install the silex debug toolbar and take a look that it's actually the query causing this:
https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler